# How to use CiviCRM REST API in external PHP code

Tags: civimember, api, php

Been trying to get this to work for hours. Help would be greatly appreciated. userkey and sitekey are replaced with actual keys.

I'm trying to run in a php file:

```
$result = curl -X POST "https://www.mysite.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/rest.php?entity=Membership&action=get&api_key=userkey&key=sitekey&json={"sequential":1,"return":"membership_type_id,id,end_date","contact_id":2,"active_only":1,"options":{"limit":1,"sort":"join_date DESC"}}";
```

I get the error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'POST' (T_STRING) in /home/spulver/civicrmapi.php on line 3
```

Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use CURL to call rest api. Here is the snippet you can ignore/remove many lines that sets curl variable.

```
$url = 'http://domain.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/rest.php?entity=Contact&action=getsingle&api_key=HR76BS710C&key=8c1cf9913fd674e08c8f27804334eb5a&json={"id":1}';

$ch = curl_init();
//http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php
//$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");

//for debugging?
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$obj = json_decode($data);
```

HTH

Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

you need to replace the url parameters **api_key** and **key** with the relevant keys. 
More information can be found in the [developer documents](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/interfaces/#rest).

Comment: in addition to @pradeep-nayak answer

Comment: Yes I have replaced the keys in my actual code. Not posting them here. THanks